# Setting UItextField value using @IBInspectable

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a hard time understanding `@IBInspectable`. Please take a look at this following code

```
@IBDesignable
class TagListMyView: UIView {

    let kCONTENT_XIB_NAME = "TagListMyView"

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameFieldValue: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var companyFieldValue: UITextField!

    @IBInspectable var border:CGFloat = 2.0{
        didSet{
            nameFieldValue.layer.borderWidth = border
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var nameValue:String = "My dummy text"{
        didSet{
            nameFieldValue.text = nameValue ----> This is not working 
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bkgColor:UIColor = UIColor.blue {
        didSet{
            contentView.layer.backgroundColor = bkgColor.cgColor ---> This is working 
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit(){
        let bundle = Bundle.init(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

**First Screen Shot**
[image: Screen Shot]

I am not able to understand why I value of the field `nameValue` is not reflecting LIVE on the storyboard. Please take a look at this below screenshot.Please take a look at storyboard attribute inspector

**Second Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Try to make `nameValue` an optional `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine for me - entering text in the `Name Value` field shows up in the `nameFieldValue` text field.

If I ***delete*** the text from that field, it shows "Default" (in light gray), but the default value of "My dummy text" does **not** get filled in.

To get the default value to show, add this line at the end of `commonInit()`:

```
    nameFieldValue.text = nameValue
```

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Not sure why it's not working for you... It's possible something is not configured / connected correctly in your XIB?

Try this in a new project....

Add the code for your `TagListMyView` class.

```
File -> New -> File... Empty User Interface
```

Save it as `TagListMyView`

Right-click on that new XIB file and select `Open As... Source Code`

Delete everything there, and paste in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14490.70" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14490.49"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="TagListMyView" customModule="UsingMyLib" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="companyFieldValue" destination="kES-3d-prB" id="hm2-Td-Hwh"/>
                <outlet property="contentView" destination="iN0-l3-epB" id="4ze-kf-v9a"/>
                <outlet property="nameFieldValue" destination="rR2-wR-SQc" id="Zce-pm-bo9"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="191"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="251" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="rR2-wR-SQc">
                    <rect key="frame" x="16" y="8" width="343" height="30"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99806135890000003" green="0.96808904409999996" blue="0.12760734560000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="19"/>
                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                </textField>
                <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="251" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kES-3d-prB">
                    <rect key="frame" x="16" y="46" width="343" height="30"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99806135890000003" green="0.96808904409999996" blue="0.12760734560000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="19"/>
                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                </textField>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="kES-3d-prB" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="NCh-WY-orP"/>
                <constraint firstItem="vUN-kp-3ea" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="kES-3d-prB" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="QSR-aS-Pbc"/>
                <constraint firstItem="rR2-wR-SQc" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="Qip-9C-I54"/>
                <constraint firstItem="kES-3d-prB" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="rR2-wR-SQc" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="R96-jo-2bN"/>
                <constraint firstItem="vUN-kp-3ea" firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="kES-3d-prB" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="Rhu-LS-9Bl"/>
                <constraint firstItem="vUN-kp-3ea" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="rR2-wR-SQc" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="XMy-BD-5em"/>
                <constraint firstItem="rR2-wR-SQc" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="z6P-St-aSt"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vUN-kp-3ea"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="138.40000000000001" y="-59.820089955022496"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Right-click on the XIB file again and select `Open As... Interface Builder XIB Document`

It should already have the custom class assigned to Owner, and the IBOutlets connected.

Add a `UIView` to the default view controller, give it appropriate constraints, and assign its Custom Class to `TagListMyView`.

Select `Editor -> Refresh All Views`, and see if it behaves as desired.

This is the `TagListMyView` class I'm using -- I believe the only change I made was to add the `nameFieldValue.text = nameValue` line at the end of `commonInit()` (and put // comment indicators in front of your notes).

```
@IBDesignable
class TagListMyView: UIView {

    let kCONTENT_XIB_NAME = "TagListMyView"

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameFieldValue: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var companyFieldValue: UITextField!

    @IBInspectable var border:CGFloat = 2.0{
        didSet{
            nameFieldValue.layer.borderWidth = border

        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var nameValue:String = "My dummy text"{
        didSet{
            nameFieldValue.text = nameValue //----> This is not working

        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bkgColor:UIColor = UIColor.blue {
        didSet{
            contentView.layer.backgroundColor = bkgColor.cgColor ///---> This is working
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit(){
        let bundle = Bundle.init(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
        nameFieldValue.text = nameValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for me. Did you make any changes in my code to make it work? Can you please share your code which is working.

Comment: Thanks I will try this code. I will accept your answer soon

Answer (score 0):

IBDesignable / IBInspectable are limited to drawing in Xcode Interface Builder. You cannot even draw shadows, but you can draw gradients – so it is a bit of this and that.
You can set the name or a value on a text field, which will be used at runtime – but it will not update in the Xcode Interface Builder.

Comment: Hi, Can you please refer me to some documentation which highlights these points. I dig down the whole internet but couldn't find any such information.

Comment: You can draw shadows.